# Permissions for user for whole disk ( and/or Partitions) in win7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, permissions, vmware

I have a linux mint partition and a win7 partition on my disk.
I am running (oracle) VM on win7, and  My goal is to boot to the linux partition with the VM.
This was not so difficult to do by creating a pseudo-vmdk  e.g.

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename mydrive.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1
```

The problem is that now in order to use the vmdk, I have to start the VM as root. This 
(i think?) is because otherwise the VM will not be able to access the second disk.
However, the second disk only has linux, so ideally I would like to give the current user permission to access it.

Is there any way in win7 to give a user permission only to the second disk as a whole?
Alternatively / Specifically : Is there any way to use the vmdkconnection to the physical partition without being admin?

I did a search on google, but did not find a way. Note that I dont want to just "take ownership" of some files, or access a usb/CD.
The (closest???) question, but with a  much different (and easier) answer might be [restricting access to volumes disk even for admin account windows](https://superuser.com/questions/205934/restricting-access-to-volumes-disk-even-for-admin-account-windows/426917#426917)